# How to populate UITableView with parsed elements?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit, nsarray

I can't get my UITableView to display my parsed elements. Here's my code:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
//elementsArray is a NSArray that is declared in .h
elementsArray = [document selectElements: @"name"];
[myTable reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return [elementsArray count];

}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [elementsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;

}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

}
```

My NSLog prints out all the elements but the elements don't get displayed in the UITableView. Everything is hooked up fine and all delegates etc. It works if I define a static NSArray like so

```
NSArray * elementsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name1",@"name2",@"name3",nil];
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You need to add a property for your "elementsArray" and syntesize it, nit just declare it in the .h folder. That said, I don't see were "document" is declared. Try logging the contents of "elementsArray" before you reload the table, to see what is in it.

Comment: I've added the property and synthesized it but still no adding to table. When I log it everything is there that should be displayed in the table. I've also tried to save the array to a file and read off the file but still no data is added. Maybe I'm doing something wrong with the array or something. idk

Comment: Did you check that the tableview is working when displaying non parsed elements ? Your problem may not come from the parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a breakpoint in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, see if elementsArray still has the right elements. From your code, it's not immediately clear how/if it's retained between events.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though you're missing a call to `retain` here:

```
elementsArray = [document selectElements: @"name"];
```

Assuming the implementation of `selectElements:` conforms to Apple's memory management guidelines, this would need to be:

```
elementsArray = [[document selectElements: @"name"] retain];
```